# DynamicMethod and Func<T> delegates

Tags: .net, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class ClassWithFuncConstructor
{
        public ClassWithFuncConstructor(Func<int> func)
    {

    }
}
```

Now I want to use the `DynamicMethod` class to emit the code needed to create an instance of the `ClassWithFuncConstructor` class like this:

```
public void DynamicMethodPrototype()
{   
    var instance = new ClassWithFuncConstructor(() => 42);
}
```

If we take a look at the code compiled for this prototype (from LinqPad), we can see that it creates another method that is the body of the function delegate and then passes a pointer to that method as the constructor parameter.

```
DynamicMethodPrototype:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0006:  brtrue.s    IL_001B
IL_0008:  ldnull      
IL_0009:  ldftn       UserQuery.<DynamicMethodPrototype>b__0
IL_000F:  newobj      System.Func<System.Int32>..ctor
IL_0014:  stsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0019:  br.s        IL_001B
IL_001B:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0020:  newobj      UserQuery+ClassWithFuncConstructor..ctor
IL_0025:  stloc.0     
IL_0026:  ret         

<DynamicMethodPrototype>b__0:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    2A 
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  br.s        IL_0005
IL_0005:  ldloc.0     
IL_0006:  ret
```

The question is how could this be done the use of the `DynamicMethod` class? 
I need to sort of create a new anonymous method aka the `<DynamicMethodPrototype>b__0:` so that I can pass a reference to that method to the constructor of the `ClassWithFuncConstructor` class.

Is this even possible to do with the `DynamicMethod` class?

Comment: Have you tried creating another `DynamicMethod` and using that from the first one?

Comment: You don't need a lambda, only a function that returns 42.